# show all equation labels when typing \eqref

Tags: equations, labels, emacs, reftex

I use AUCTeX + RefTeX a lot and really like the convenience. Is there a way of automatically showing all equation labels with I type `\eqref{` followed by a <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the Emacs window? I know that <kbd>C-) e</kbd> does this; but I would like to shorten the process to automatically run <kbd>C-) e</kbd> every time I type `\eqref{` followed by a <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`company-reftex`](https://github.com/TheBB/company-reftex).  Have you tried it?

Comment: I've added the emacs tag, seemed rather relevant